# Multicast UDP packets are received at multiple sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, multicast

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I have a process which contains 2 threads. The first thread sends 5 UDP packets through lo interface, each with a different mcast dst address: 224.0.24.10, 239.255.1.1, 239.255.1.2, 239.255.1.3, 239.255.1.4. These packets have the same dport = 60000.

The 2nd thread creates 5 sockets and tries to receive those mcast packets. It looks like this:

```
int sd;
struct sockaddr_in sock;
struct ip_mreq group;
int reuse = 1;

sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&reuse, sizeof(reuse));

bzero((char *)&sock, sizeof(sock));
sock.sin_family = AF_INET;
sock.sin_port = htons(60000);
sock.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

bind(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&sock, sizeof(sock));

group.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = dip;
group.imr_interface.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in *)(&(ifr.ifr_addr)))->sin_addr.s_addr;   //This is the IP of lo: 127.0.0.1

setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char *)&group, sizeof(group));
```

I left out all the error checking in the code sample above. I have them in my real code.

Basically, the code above is in a function which is called 5 times, each call has a different dip. The sd(s) created are then set into a fd_set where select() is used to receive from all 5 sockets.

What I saw is that socket associated with 224.0.24.10 receives the correct packet.

But the other 4 sockets receive ALL packets to 239.255.1.*. For example, socket associated with 239.255.1.1 shall receives packets with dip = 239.255.1.1 only. But it receives packets with dip = 239.255.1.1 - 239.255.1.4.

I turned on IP_PKTINFO and used in_pktinfo to dump dip in the received packets and confirm that these dip are correct. But why are the packets received by the wrong sockets?

Any solution?

Thanks,
Yao

Comment: Do you really have 5 separate sockets all listening on `0.0.0.0:60000` at the same time?

Comment: I changed sock.sin_addr.s_addr = dip. Now it's working correctly.

Comment: The IP is not 0.0.0.0. They are 224.*, 239.* I list above.

Comment: `INADDR_ANY` is `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Why on earth are you using multicast restricted to the local host?